# Creating DialogFragment with EditText

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android, started it about a month ago, and now I'm trying to make a "Shopping List" app for the sake of practice. In this app I have a ListView, where user can insert items via EditText above that ListView. When user longClick on item, ContextMenu with "Edit", "Delete" and "Mark" fields appears. I have already made "Delete" button work, but I still have problems with "Edit" function. To make this function work I created DialogFragment class, so when user presses the "Edit" button, this DialogFragment appears. This DF has EditText field, where we enter data we want to change. Here is DialogFragment class code:

```
public class AlertEdit extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       AlertDialog.Builder bd = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
       LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
       bd.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert, null))
               .setTitle("Edit")
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                       ((MyActivity)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
                   }
               })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ((MyActivity)getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
                    }
                });

        return bd.create();
    }
```

as you can see, we have positive button here, which calls doPositiveClick method from MyActivity, which appears to be the main activity.

```
.setPositiveButton(R.string.save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   ((MyActivity)getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
               }
```

So, here is the MyActivity class code:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

         lw = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
         edtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        alertEd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alertEdit);


        goods = new ArrayList<String>();

        adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, goods);
        lw.setAdapter(adapter);

        lw.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {

            }
        });
        registerForContextMenu(lw);

        edtxt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                        goods.add(0, edtxt.getText().toString());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        edtxt.setText("");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
               return false;
            }
        });
        }

    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo info){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, info);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);

    }
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        position = (int) info.id;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.cnt_mnu_delete:
                goods.remove(position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            case R.id.cnt_mnu_edit:   
    }


        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void doPositiveClick()
{    
}
public void doNegativeClick()
{ 
}
public void showDialog()
{
    DialogFragment frag = new AlertEdit();
    frag.show(getFragmentManager(), "edit");
}
}
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to create that Edit function. I tryied to use AdapterContextMenuInfo, but it works only in onContextItemSelected method, because it requires and Item to work with. Hope you help me and sorry for the possible lack of information, ask me any additional questions please. 
P.S. I'm trying to make this dialog for almost two weeks already and I'm really frustrated because of that.

Comment: Does your buttons are working fine? I mean can you see whether edit  click event responds? and if yes what all the fields that your user can edit. If you would like to share your code, mail me to mahesh.venkat27@gmail.com, please I will try to help you out. It sounds quite tricky and Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using this method - it's simple and you may adapt it to your needs:

First of all make an interface to handle your result, for example:

```
public interface OnDialogResultListener {
    public void onDialogResult(String result);
}
```

Then use your dialog with additional view, like this:

```
public void showDialogAndGetResult(final int title, final String message, final String initialText, final OnDialogResultListener listener) {
// additional View - use appropriate View to your needs:
final EditText editText = new EditText(this);
editText.setText(initialText);

new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)//
    .setTitle(title)//
    .setMessage(message)//
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.onDialogResult(editText.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    })//
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)//
    .setView(editText)//
    .show();
}
```

At last implement this interface in your activity:

```
public class YourActivity Extends Activity implements OnDialogResultListener{
...
    @Override
    public void onDialogResult(String result) {
        //do what you need
    }
...
}
```

**Edit**:
You may replace EditText by any View, including Layouts.
 
Still you may use the same scheme to return result from your DialogFragment descendant - just pass OnDialogResultListener in constructor or initializing method. 
I would say AlertDialog is more lightweight and DialogFragment allows more control and you may use both according to your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much fro your reply! My question now is: why must I use editText as a view? Can't I use a custom layout?

Comment: I've edited post according to your additional question, please take a look